# Django OnClick Submit Button not showing confirmation pop-up

Tags: django, forms, button, onclick, submit

I have a form in which I wanted to have the Submit button have a pop-up to ask the user if they are sure they want to submit the form with the options 'OK' and 'cancel'. This seemed to work on all of my other forms but this one is not. Instead of showing the pop-up and asking the user for confirmation, it just submits.

Wondering if this might be because of a clash with the JS or another part of the logic in the form...

Code:

```
{% extends "prod/page_base.html" %}

{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{{ edit_add }} product configuration{% endblock %}

{% block dajax %}
    {% dajaxice_js_import %}
    <script src="{% static 'dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#id_line").val() != "group1" && $("#id_line").val() != "group2") {
        $("#group_fields").hide();
    }
    $("#id_line").click(function() {
        if ($("#id_line").val() != "group1" && $("#id_line").val() != "group2") {
            $("#group_fields").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#group_fields").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block pagetitle %}{{ edit_add }} Product Configuration{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}

{% if form.errors or formset.errors %}
<p class='error_note'><strong>Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.</strong></p>
{% endif %}

    <form class="edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <p>
        {{ form.name.errors }}
        <label for="id_name">Product Name:</label>
        {{ form.name }}
        </p>
        <p>
        {{ form.line.errors }}
        <label for="id_line">Product Line:</label>
        {{ form.line }}
        </p>
        <div id="group_fields">
        <p>
        {{ form.type.errors }}
        <label for="id_type">Type:</label>
        {{ form.type }}
        </p>
        </div>
        <p>
        {{ form.reason_for_change.errors }}
        <label for="id_reason_for_change">Reason for change (mandatory):</label>
        {{ form.reason_for_change }}
        </p>
        <input class="button" type="Submit" value="Commit changes" onclick="return confirm('Submit changes?')">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does the `confirm()` function look like?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of JS, you can't really do this with a submit button. So the best option is to replace the submit button with a normal button and submit through the JS function.

To do this you will need to give the form an id:

```
<form id="form1" class="edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <p>
    {{ form.name.errors }}
    <label for="id_name">Product Name:</label>
    {{ form.name }}
    </p>
    <p>
    {{ form.line.errors }}
    <label for="id_line">Product Line:</label>
    {{ form.line }}
    </p>
    <div id="group_fields">
    <p>
    {{ form.type.errors }}
    <label for="id_type">Type:</label>
    {{ form.type }}
    </p>
    </div>
    <p>
    {{ form.reason_for_change.errors }}
    <label for="id_reason_for_change">Reason for change (mandatory):</label>
    {{ form.reason_for_change }}
    </p>
    <input class="button" value="Commit changes" onclick="confirm('Submit changes?')">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function confirm(str){
    confirm = window.confirm(str);
    if (confirm == true){
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
}
```